# Android logcat command line to output file after app collapse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logging, logcat

I am debugging an app. I would left it run overnight and wanna get the log file when it collapses. It is v likely that it collapse at night when no one is in the office. What make it reli tricky is that the app will reopen automatically even after it collapses when it doesn't run for a while. This would automatically clear the log at the time it collapsed.

Is there a way to output the log to a txt file right after it collapses by using logcat command? or make it automatically output log at fixed interval? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, plz excuse my stupid question. I finally managed to get it myself...
I ended up coding a batch file as follows in order to generate log file every 5 min to my local environment.

```
:loop
adb logcat - d time >> %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
timeout /t 300
goto loop
```